# What "Hack" means in the languages bar on gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I've noticed, on the languages bar, that 1.3% of the languages used on my project are "Hack".

I was just wondering what this "hack" actually means ?

Answer (score 10):

As explained in this issue: https://github.com/github/linguist/issues/4229#issuecomment-412846757

A `php` file is considered a `hack` file by Gitlab and Github when there is only HTML code in it.